# Ergodic theorem under condition $E[\sup Y]<\infty$ instead of $E|Y|<\infty$?

Tags: parameter-estimation, estimation, ergodic-theory

In my lecture, the ergodic theorem is given as: let $X_t,t\in \mathbb{Z}$ be stationary and ergodic, $Y_t=f(X_t,X_{t-1},...)$ measurable with $E|Y_0|<\infty$, then
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}Y_k\rightarrow E(Y_0) f.s.$$

But I have found in some papers like [here](https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/%7Emaling/paper/McAleer-Ling.pdf) page 99 asumption 1 (i) or [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3453826) page 25 iv) using condition $E[\sup Y_t<\infty]$. Those assumptions should be given to use the ergodic theorem, so I wonder if there is a version of ergodic theorem under this condition?

Thank you in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mentioned papers, the sequence $(Y_t)$ depends on some parameter $\theta$ and can be denoted as $(Y_t(\theta))_t$. The authors require $\sup_\theta\lvert Y_t(\theta)\rvert$ to be integrable, not the supremum over $t$.
If you want simply to apply the ergodic theorem for a fixed $\theta_0$, the you only need $\lvert Y_1(\theta_0)\rvert$ to be integrable.

Actually, unless $Y_0$ is bounded, integrability of $\sup_t \lvert Y_t\rvert$ is very unlikely to happen. In the i.i.d. case, you can compute the distribution of this random variable.

Comment: I believe it's $\sup Y_t$ instead of $\sup|Y_t|$? In the mentioned papers. A little bit weaker.

Comment: True. But this is still a supremum on the parameter set, not over $t$.

Comment: So you mean the authors actually claimed that $Y_t<\infty$ is already sufficient for ergodic theorem?

Comment: No. I mean that a sufficient condition for the ergodic theorem (that you can find in any textbook on ergodic theory) is integrability of $Y_0$. In the context of the linked paper, the authors need something more because they certainly want something stronger than the ergodic theorem.